# How to interpret the odds ratio for a coefficient (slope)

Tags: generalized-linear-model, odds-ratio

I'm trying to interpret the odds ratio for a coefficient (particularly for a slope that represents the change - in odds - of the outcome over time).

If I convert an odds ratio to probability, for example, the odds ratio `1.26`, using the formula:

$$p\quad =\quad odds\_ ratio\quad /\quad (1\quad +\quad odds\_ ratio)$$

The I obtain `.557` for p. I'm having trouble connection this probability to change in the response (over time).

Comment: You need to distinguish between odds and odds ratios. The former you can convert, the latter not, into a probability.

Comment: Thank you. For an odds *ratio* of 1.26, could I interpret this as something like "with each additional time point, there is a 26% greater odds of the outcome"

Comment: That would be the usual interpretation. Note that the coefficient for the intercept is (log) odds not (log) odds ratio so can be converted.

Comment: Thank you. A bit confused - how is the intercept different than other coefs?

Comment: The constant would be the baseline odds; the odds of the event when all explanatory variables are zero. Discussing the baseline odds in the results section of an article is a useful way of reminding the audience what the difference is between odds and probability, and thus the difference between an odds ratio (which you have) and a risk ratio (which you have not).